# Django: How to add 2 days to an existing date entered by user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to add a a payment due date 2 days after the event

```
class Payment(models.Model):       
    event_date = models.DateField()        
    payment_due_date = models.DateField()    


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["payment_due_date"]

    def payment_due_date(self):
         event_date = self.event_date
         return event_date + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
```

> Pycharm gives me a error highligting `Expected type 'timedelta', got 'DateField' instead more... (Ctrl+F1)`

how can I fix this issue

Error in Terminal

> match = date_re.match(value)
>   TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could override your `save()` method in your model.

**Note** that a `DateTimeField` in Django becomes a `datetime.datetime` object. So to retrieve the date from it, you need to call `field.date()`.

Example:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Payment(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
    payment_due_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["payment_due_date"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.payment_due_date is None:
            self.payment_due_date = self.event_date.date() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
        super(Payment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `Expected type 'timedelta', got 'DateField' instead more... (Ctrl+F1)` getting this error in pycharm

Comment: @MarcoBianchi Just curious...what if you try `datetime.timedelta(hours=48)` instead of `days`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: I mean this code works with something like `datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)` Its just that If I add a django field it gives the above error

Comment: @MarcoBianchi I think you might need to call the `date()` method on the field. See my updated code above.

Comment: I think this did it. Pycharm not giving any error. Will check the code